# How do I return MVC File ActionResult of PDF over jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, modal-dialog

*Note:  I am not wanting to display the PDF inline with the modal.  Rather, I am looking to have the browser acknowledge the file and allow the user to save or open it.*

I have a jQueryUI modal dialog in MVC 4.  The dialog IS modal.  The content of the dialog is from a Partial Views which works fine.  I have only one button on the dialog itself and have successfully gotten all the JavaScript to deal with client side data entry checking.

What is giving me a headache is that I have one button embedded in the Partial View that is to display a PDF file.  I can successfully call a JavaScript function that calls the controller that gets the file from another server.  I can even get the file converted to a byte array and the last line is 
`return File(contents, "application/pdf", "PropsedChanges.pdf");`

However it will not open as I suspect that the modal dialog is preventing it.

I have done something similar outside of the model dialog and it gives me the save/open option at the bottom of the screen for IE or in the correct manner in other browsers.

Is there a way to display the PDF in a registered PDF viewer on the client's PC/Device outside of the browser needing to ask if they want to save or open it? Which, as I suspect, is not happening due to the modal dialog.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the answer. I am trying to open the PDF in new browser window but not PDF Viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult GetPdf(Model modelo)
    {  
        return File(Pdf bytes[], "application/pdf");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new window to open your PDF.  Like target="_new" or "blank".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.net 5, install MvcPdfActionResult via nuget

```
PM> Install-Package MvcPdfActionResult
```

Simply use return type as PdfActionResult in the controller will output PDF document instead of HTML. This converts HTML to PDF using the iTextXmlWorker Library.

```
  ...
  return PdfActionResult(model);
}
```

Generates pdf documents from your razor views within an asp.net 5 MVC project. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcPdfActionResult/